# Typecasting with variable

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have an enum that will indicate the identifier and class to use for a tableViewCell.

```
enum Settings: String {
    case Delete = "deleteCell"

    var cellType: UITableViewCell.Type {
        switch self {
            case .Delete: return DeleteCell.self
        }
    }
}
```

In my tableView rowForIndexPath I am able to get the cell with the reuseIdendifyer, but it won't recognize the `setting` object to get the class. The error here is `Use of undeclared type 'setting'`, specifically on the end of the line.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let setting = Settings.enabledSettings[indexPath.row]

    return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: setting.rawValue, for: indexPath) as! setting.cellType
}
```

It's not bad now with just the one object, but this will be growing soon and it's mostly the same thing, just changing the class name. Is it possible to pull the class type from another source like this so I can keep the rowForIndexPath function short and sweet, or do I need to do something like this?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let setting = Settings.enabledSettings[indexPath.row]

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: setting.rawValue, for: indexPath)

    if setting == .Delete { cell = cell as! DeleteCell }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: What is the return type of `Settings.enabledSettings[indexPath.row]`?

Comment: @AlfredWoo Sorry, I forgot that was left off. This is shared code across several targets. Each target will extend `Settings` and add an array of settings that are used for that version of the app. In this sample it's pulling `Settings.Delete`.